# Extracting Pandas multiindex from dataframe with NaT

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am using pandas to parse an Excel spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet has several worksheets, each of which look like the following.  Notice that each column has values that correspond to different dates, and has different lengths:

[image: Excel spreadsheet]

For whatever reason, when pandas parses the Excel spreadsheet, the first worksheet parses the first column of dates as the index (even though index_col parameter has been specified as None).  That's still manageable.

However, in the other worksheets, it parses the index as a multiindex:

[image: Screenshot of multiindex]

What I want to do is ultimately rebuild the dataframe so that they all share a common date index, and for any dates with no values is filled with NaN.  However, I can't seem to extract the dates from the multiindex to even begin this process.

I've tried to perform `reset_index()` on the dataframe on both levels 0 and 1 but it complains about `IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.`  I've also tried to `unstack()`, but that complains about `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/panas.read_excel.html) with parameters `parse_cols`, `header`, `index_col`. Then create DataFrames from each pair by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them to one:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('f_name.xlsx', parse_cols=[0, 1, 3, 4, 7 , 8], index_col=0, header=0)
#if you need reset NaT in index, but it is not necessary
#df.index = df.index.to_series().fillna(0)
print df
            Column_val1 Unnamed: 1  Column_val2 Unnamed: 3  Column_val3
1999-01-01            4 2000-01-01            5 2000-01-01            5
1999-01-02            1 2000-01-02            7 2000-01-02            7
1999-01-03            2 2000-01-03            8 2000-01-03            8
1999-01-04            3 2000-01-04            3 2000-01-04            3
1999-01-05            3 2000-01-05            6 2000-01-05            6
1999-01-06            3 2000-01-06            9 2000-01-06            9
1999-01-07            4 2000-01-07            1 2000-01-07            1
1999-01-08            6 2000-01-08            5 2000-01-08            5
1999-01-09            8 2000-01-09            2 2000-01-09            2
1999-01-10            2 2000-01-10            3 2000-01-10            3
1999-01-11            4 2000-01-11           47 2000-01-11           47
1999-01-12            5 2000-01-12            2 2000-01-12            2
NaT                 NaN 2000-01-13            8 2000-01-13            8
NaT                 NaN 2000-01-14            2 2000-01-14            2
NaT                 NaN 2000-01-15           87 2000-01-15           87
NaT                 NaN 2000-01-16            6 2000-01-16            6
NaT                 NaN 2000-01-17           89 2000-01-17           89
NaT                 NaN        NaT          NaN 2000-01-18            7
NaT                 NaN        NaT          NaN 2000-01-19            8
```

```
print df['Column_val1']
1999-01-01     4
1999-01-02     1
1999-01-03     2
1999-01-04     3
1999-01-05     3
1999-01-06     3
1999-01-07     4
1999-01-08     6
1999-01-09     8
1999-01-10     2
1999-01-11     4
1999-01-12     5
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
Name: Column_val1, dtype: float64
```

```
print df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 1])['Column_val2']
Unnamed: 1
2000-01-01     5
2000-01-02     7
2000-01-03     8
2000-01-04     3
2000-01-05     6
2000-01-06     9
2000-01-07     1
2000-01-08     5
2000-01-09     2
2000-01-10     3
2000-01-11    47
2000-01-12     2
2000-01-13     8
2000-01-14     2
2000-01-15    87
2000-01-16     6
2000-01-17    89
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
Name: Column_val2, dtype: float64
```

```
print df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 3])['Column_val3']
Unnamed: 3
2000-01-01     5
2000-01-02     7
2000-01-03     8
2000-01-04     3
2000-01-05     6
2000-01-06     9
2000-01-07     1
2000-01-08     5
2000-01-09     2
2000-01-10     3
2000-01-11    47
2000-01-12     2
2000-01-13     8
2000-01-14     2
2000-01-15    87
2000-01-16     6
2000-01-17    89
2000-01-18     7
2000-01-19     8
Name: Column_val3, dtype: int64
```

```
df = pd.concat([df['Column_val1'], 
                df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 1])['Column_val2'], 
                df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 3])['Column_val3'] ])

#better is use sort index
df = df.sort_index()
print df
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
NaT          NaN
1999-01-01     4
1999-01-02     1
1999-01-03     2
1999-01-04     3
1999-01-05     3
1999-01-06     3
1999-01-07     4
1999-01-08     6
1999-01-09     8
1999-01-10     2
1999-01-11     4
1999-01-12     5
2000-01-01     5
2000-01-01     5
2000-01-02     7
2000-01-02     7
2000-01-03     8
2000-01-03     8
2000-01-04     3
2000-01-04     3
2000-01-05     6
2000-01-05     6
2000-01-06     9
2000-01-06     9
2000-01-07     1
2000-01-07     1
2000-01-08     5
2000-01-08     5
2000-01-09     2
2000-01-09     2
2000-01-10     3
2000-01-10     3
2000-01-11    47
2000-01-11    47
2000-01-12     2
2000-01-12     2
2000-01-13     8
2000-01-13     8
2000-01-14     2
2000-01-14     2
2000-01-15    87
2000-01-15    87
2000-01-16     6
2000-01-16     6
2000-01-17    89
2000-01-17    89
2000-01-18     7
2000-01-19     8
dtype: float64
```

```
#if you need remove rows where index is NaT
print df[pd.notnull(df.index)]
1999-01-01     4
1999-01-02     1
1999-01-03     2
1999-01-04     3
1999-01-05     3
1999-01-06     3
1999-01-07     4
1999-01-08     6
1999-01-09     8
1999-01-10     2
1999-01-11     4
1999-01-12     5
2000-01-01     5
2000-01-01     5
2000-01-02     7
2000-01-02     7
2000-01-03     8
2000-01-03     8
2000-01-04     3
2000-01-04     3
2000-01-05     6
2000-01-05     6
2000-01-06     9
2000-01-06     9
2000-01-07     1
2000-01-07     1
2000-01-08     5
2000-01-08     5
2000-01-09     2
2000-01-09     2
2000-01-10     3
2000-01-10     3
2000-01-11    47
2000-01-11    47
2000-01-12     2
2000-01-12     2
2000-01-13     8
2000-01-13     8
2000-01-14     2
2000-01-14     2
2000-01-15    87
2000-01-15    87
2000-01-16     6
2000-01-16     6
2000-01-17    89
2000-01-17    89
2000-01-18     7
2000-01-19     8
dtype: float64
```